# Why is there white space on the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working to design my wedding website, but I've came across a bug I am struggling with. I am only using HTML and CSS. The idea is to alternate between scrolling and fixed backgrounds, and it works brilliantly going up and down. I was very proud of myself. I have copied the CSS below. (I cleaned it up, it was a little jumbled when I copy and pasted.)

http://mattvwhittle.com/WeddingWebsite/index.html

The problem is: there is a chunk of white space on the right if you scroll that way.

Any suggestions?

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body, html, main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#bg-fixed-1 {
  background-image: url("images/skyline.jpg");
}
#bg-fixed-1 h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 80px;
}
#bg-fixed-1 h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 140px;
}
#bg-scroll-2 {
  background-color: #FCFBF7;
}
#bg-fixed-3 {
  background-image: url("images/bandw.jpg");
}
#bg-scroll-4 {
  background-color: #FCFBF7;
}
#bg-fixed-5 {
  background-image: url("images/cover.jpg");
}
#bg-scroll-6 {
  background-color: #FCFBF7;
}
.scrolling-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ^^ was going to say put it on the `body { overflow-x: hidden;}`. don't know why it's happening though.

Comment: I can't scroll that way cause there is no scrollbar. I don't see any whitespace either.

Comment: @Rob I guess he fixed it now

Comment: Thanks for checking guys. Thanks rob scott for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your h1 and h2s are causing this. If you inspect them you will see that they push the page out.

Several options. I'd go with replacing left with padding-left or setting display: inline.

```
#bg-fixed-1 h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

#bg-fixed-1 h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  padding-left: 140px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I could not figure out what I was doing wrong! I'm new to the web design world. I really appreciate your answer!